Can't load current projects since updating or open composer template in new projects in QGIS
I work on QGIS on various projects which are saved on Onedrive and since Thursday morning I can no longer open old or current projects.
I opened a colleague's QGIS to work on the project with them and found layers missing as I had an older version of QGIS (3.30.1). They did not have the QGIS project file open at the time.
I then downloaded the latest version of QGIS Long Term Release (3.34.13) and since then have had problems.
Any QGIS projects that were created before Thursday freeze while trying to load random layers (it changes each time) after going through the blue loading bar. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the most recent version of QGIS and archived versions with no results.
I have also tried using QGIS on an old laptop and this now cannot open QGIS projects after opening a project created after Thursday.  My colleague is having the same issues with her QGIS.
I can create new projects and load the old layers in which works and these new projects can then be open and closed without problem until I try to create a figure from a saved template then the whole thing freezes. We use a figure template (QGIS Composer Template) in the layout manager.
Bizarrely, two of my colleagues are having no issues with QGIS and both are using different versions of QGIS (3.30.1 and 3.34.07).  They have not opened the original project I opened on Thursday.
An image of an unloaded QGIS project is below.  

A standard response to funky project behavior is to rename the QGIS appdata folder (all projects closed) and see if the new one QGIS creates solves the problems.  This folder is not changed by reinstalls.  If it does then customize it.  If it doesn't then rename the original back and look for other solutions.  It's in C:\Users\your user name here\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3.  The fact a colleague is also having problems may mean the composer template file is corrupted?  Note, I don't see much in your image.
